# .NET ORM that Supports Oracle 8i

Tags: asp.net, oracle, orm, oracle8i

I have been tasked with creating a rewrite of a ColdFusion application with ASP.NET MVC3. I would like to use an ORM with this application to speed development.

However I have had some trouble finding one that supports the Oracle 8i database that the existing data is already in.

Does anyone know any ORM systems that will solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this - http://bltoolkit.net/
It actually has better support for LINQ than Linq2SQL and it has Oracle provider as well.
It's a kind of lightweight but pretty powerful at the same time.

Comment: Awesome, I'll give it a shot when I get to work. The problem I was running into was that most ORM's only support back to Oracle 9 and this is communicating with an Oracle 8i database. Hopefully this works out for me!